# Flutter: How do I read a barcode using a Honeywell handheld that runs Android?

Tags: android, flutter, barcode, handheld, honeywell

I have a handheld scan gun, the brand is Honeywell and model is CK65. I need to be able to read a standard barcode, i.e. not a QR code. I have the flutter demo app running on the device, now I just need to make a test function that can read a barcode and print it to the console, but I'm not sure how to even get started. How do I do this?

Comment: Look for a barcode scanner SDK made by the manufacturer. A quick search brings up: https://sps.honeywell.com/us/en/software/productivity/development-tools/mobility-sdk-android and any details/SDKs require registration. The code will probably be in Java and you'll have to write your own [custom platform channel](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)

Comment: I am also looking for flutter library for handheld scan gun. Brand is Honeywell Android 10-AQ2. I am not getting any library that will read bar code using scan gun. Need help if any one have done this.